# Accessing fields of Mysqli Object

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have a mysqli object, which has this inside -

```
mysqli_result object {
  current_field => (int) 0
  field_count => (int) 6
  lengths => null
  num_rows => (int) 304
  type => (int) 0
}
```

This object is in the variable `$result`

Why can't I simply access the number of rows by doing this -

```
    CDB::UseDB('localhost', 'x', 'x', 'x'); 

    $sql = "select * from table";

    $result = CDB::ExecuteQuery($sql);

    echo $result->num_rows;
```

How are you actually meant to access that value?

Comment: You should be able to do what you are trying to do. So show us some more code and maybe we can spot the hiccup

Comment: Edited, but not much to it really

Comment: So how do you make the connection to the database

Comment: Yea but how does the class make the connection

Comment: @RiggsFolly: but i think query is working `num_rows => (int) 304`

Comment: @devpro Yea, so do I which means that `echo $result->num_rows;` should work! Right?

Comment: Does `$result = CDB::ExecuteQuery($sql);` return an array of results by any chance???

Comment: @RiggsFolly: no idea what is CDB

Comment: it returns mysqli_result object, when I access $result->num_rows it returns null

Comment: so, run your query in phpMyAdmin and chk getting result or not?

Comment: I will try using the native Mysqli method of connecting and querying.. see what happens

Comment: Is CDB a class you got from somewhere?

Comment: Ran with native mysql functions and voila! It let me access the num_rows field of the class... Must be an issue with my CDB class then. .. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of mysqli, there is absolutely not a single problem accessing whatever `mysqli_result` class instance properties.

```
echo $result->num_rows;
```

will give you the number of rows

```
echo $result->num_fields;
```

the number of fields and so on

While speaking of whatever CDB thingy, nobody have an idea what's it about.

Comment: Maybe CDB is causing the problem